# C# asp.net create string list from a another list which returns list of class objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list which returns class objects. For dropdownlist data bind purpose I need to create string list from previous list. My main requirement is I need to get two fields(datavalue,datatext) to the dropdownlist from database. Can someone help me to do this

```
class RoleData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

private List<RoleData> EmpRoleDataBind(){
        List<RoleData> RoleList = new List<RoleData>();
        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        string query = "select emp_role_id,description from emp_role";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
        MySqlDataReader msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (msdr.Read())
        {

            RoleList.Add(
                new RoleData()
                {
                    id = Convert.ToString(msdr["emp_role_id"]),
                    value = Convert.ToString(msdr["description"])
                }    
            );
        }
        msdr.Close();
        conn.Close();
        return RoleList;
    }
```

Comment: It seems you created RoleList with desired column, so what else you want?

Comment: @Adil from that list I want to get id as datavalue and value as datatext for a dropdown list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `DropDownList` to your list and assign the class property names to `DropDownList` attributes `DataValueField`, and `DataTextField`

```
dropdownlist1.DataSource = EmpRoleDataBind();
dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "id";
dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "value";
dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```

**As a additional Note**

- You probably need to capitalize the first letter of Property, see MSDN article [Property Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
- As the method `EmpRoleDataBind` returns list of *Employee-Role* records, I would name it `GetEmpRoleData` instead of `EmpRoleDataBind` as It does not bind the `DropDownList`.